# Writing universal law of gravitation as a function of position with respect to time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, differential-equations

I wasn't sure whether this question belongs here or on the maths page. Anyway I'm new here, and this may be a stupid question, so please forgive my ignorance.

Given that the force of gravity can be expressed as:

$$F =  \dfrac{\mathrm{GM_1M_2} }{\mathrm{r^2}} $$

Assuming a two body system, is it possible to write this as a differential equation that gives the position of a particle with respect to time? I thought that a good start would be dividing by mass to give the acceleration, but alas I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming a two body system, is it possible to write this as a differential equation that gives the position of a particle with respect to time?

Yes. For two gravitating point masses, $m_1$ at $\mathbf r_1$ and $m_2$ at $\mathbf r_2$, the equations of motion for each particle are

$$m_1\frac{d^2\mathbf r_1(t)}{dt^2}=-\frac{Gm_1m_2(\mathbf r_1(t)-\mathbf r_2(t))}{| \mathbf r_1(t)-\mathbf r_2(t)|^3}$$

and

$$m_2\frac{d^2\mathbf r_2(t)}{dt^2}=-\frac{Gm_1m_2(\mathbf r_2(t)-\mathbf r_1(t))}{| \mathbf r_2(t)-\mathbf r_1(t)|^3}.$$

These are coupled second-order vector differential equations.

One then usually considers the separation vector $\mathbf r= \mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2$ which turns out to satisfy the single uncoupled second-order vector equation

$$\frac{d^2\mathbf r(t)}{dt^2}=-\frac{G(m_1+m_2)\mathbf r(t)}{| \mathbf r(t)|^3},$$

which can be solved analytically. (For example, one type of solution is a bound elliptical orbit.)

For more information, see the Wikipedia articles “[Two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem)”, “[Gravitational two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_two-body_problem)”, and “[Kepler orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit)”.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to plug your expression into Newton's second law of motion:

$\sum F = ma$;

Then, if gravity is the only relevant force on the body:

$$F = \dfrac{GmM}{r^2} = m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$

where $a = \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.

Same applies to other force laws, like Coulomb's electrostatic force expression, or Hooke's spring force expression. These give you forces, but to relate force to motion, you need to plug them into Newton's second law of motion.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Try using MathJax for formatting, makes it easier to read for everyone.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024